# Java program suddenly ending in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am currently trying to code a text-based hangman. If you choose to guess a letter, the program suddenly ends after executing line 53. Please tell me why this is happening since I could not figure it out.

This is some of my Java code:

```
package hangman;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class Hangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner chez = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner waffle = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        StringBuilder displayWord = new StringBuilder("______________________________");
        String theWord = null;
        String preLetter;
        //String sbDisplayWord;
        char letter = 0;
        int randomNumber;
        int lengthOfWord;
        int numberOfLetterInWord = 0;
        int gDisplay;
        int guessWordNumber = 0;
        String guessWord;
        RandomWord troll = new RandomWord();    
        randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(12);
        //Fill var with the word.
        theWord = troll.wordDecide(randomNumber);

        System.out.println ("Welcome to Hangman!");

        lengthOfWord=theWord.length( );
        System.out.println("This word has " + lengthOfWord + " letters.");

        System.out.println("You have 20 guesses.");

        for (int g =19; g >= 0; g--) {    

            System.out.println("If you want to guess the word, type 0. If you want to guess a letter, type 1.");
            guessWordNumber=chez.nextInt();

            if (guessWordNumber==0) {
                System.out.println("Enter the word now. Remember, don't capitalize it.");
                guessWord=waffle.nextLine();
                if (guessWord.equals(theWord)) {
                    System.out.println("YOU WIN");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, this wasn't the correct word.");
                }
            } else if (guessWordNumber==1) {

                System.out.println("Please enter the letter you wish to guess with.");
                //System.out.println("It will tell you if you have guessed right for any of the letters. If it is blank, that means none of the letters match.");
                preLetter=chez.nextLine();

                if (preLetter.length()>0) {
                    letter=preLetter.charAt(0);
                } else {
                    System.exit(0);
                }


                System.out.println("");
                for(int i = 0; i <= lengthOfWord -1; i++ ) {     //-Eshan

                    if (letter == theWord.charAt( i )) {

                        numberOfLetterInWord=i+1;
                        System.out.println("This letter matches with letter number " + numberOfLetterInWord + " in the word.");
                        displayWord.setCharAt(i, letter);
                    } else {

                        numberOfLetterInWord=i+1;
                        System.out.println("This letter doesn't match with letter number " + numberOfLetterInWord + " in the word.");

                    }       


                }

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("The word so far is " + displayWord);
                System.out.println("");
                gDisplay = g + 1;
                System.out.println("You have " + gDisplay + " guesses left.");

            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }

        System.out.println("GAME OVER");
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

This is another portion of my Java code:

```
package hangman;

public class RandomWord {
    private static String[] wordArray = {
        "psychology",
        "keratin",
        "nostalgia",
        "pyromaniac",
        "chlorophyl",
        "derivative",
        "unitard",
        "pterodactyl",
        "xylophone",
        "excommunicate",
        "obituary",
        "infinitesimal",
        "concupiscent",
    };

    public String wordDecide(int randomNumber) {
        String theWord;
        theWord = wordArray[randomNumber];
        return theWord;
    }

}
```

Comment: A comment on code-coupling.  `RandomWord` should not need to take an argument with the random number.  The size of the array of words is known only inside `RandomWord`, so the random number should be generated inside `RandomWord` as in `randomNumber=Random.nextInt(wordArray.size)` and not passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [Scanner#nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) does not consume newline characters, this line

```
guessWordNumber = chez.nextInt();
```

passes a newline character through to

```
preLetter = chez.nextLine();
```

but the `Scanner` now does not block as it has already received input. The `String` `preLetter` is now of empty so causes the program to exit.

Try using `Scanner#nextLine` which consumes newline characters:

```
guessWordNumber = Integer.parseInt(chez.nextLine());
```